# Prepend the content of a class into an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, prepend

I'm trying to move (prepend specifically) the content of a class into a div.

Here is the class I want to be moved:

```
<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice">
   <span class="PageText_L483n">
      <span itemprop='price'>$11.00</span> per 2 oz bag</span>
</font>
```

And here is the id I want it to be moved into:

```
<td valign="top">
   <span class="PageText_L71n">Quantity:</span>
   <input type="text" class="v65-productdetail-cartqty" name="QTY.KCJ-CP" size="3">
</td>
```

And here is the current unsuccessful jQuery attempt:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#v65-productdetail-action-wrapper").prepend(".PageText_L483n");
});
</script>
```

You can't tell from the provided code but "#v65-productdetail-action-wrapper" is the container that the second block of code is in. As you probably already know, this is simply prepending the literal string ".PageText_L483n", not its content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#v65-productdetail-action-wrapper").prepend($(".PageText_L483n").first());
```

To remove

```
$(".PageText_L483n").first().html("");
```

Or

```
$(".PageText_L483n").first().remove();
```

Both should work.

What you will have to do for the break is append a 
 to the class and the prepend it to the id.

```
$("#v65-productdetail-action-wrapper").prepend($(".PageText_L483n").first().append("<br>"));
```

Should do it.

Comment: This kind of worked, though there are two problems: 1) It moved the text but it's not styled at all. How can I preserve the style? And 2) It did not get rid of the original text, so now it displays twice. How can I make it also hide the original text?

Comment: Remove the `.html()` from the code given and it should work. You can't "copy" styles that easily - you would be best setting your CSS to style the element in both locations.

Comment: This is so so so close, though there is still one problem, which is it's not appearing directly above the content of the id, but rather next to it, which pushes the other content over. Here is a picture of what it looks like now: http://i.imgur.com/YOJPeSQ.png . Is there a way I could add a break tag or something in addition to appending it?

Comment: If you want it above the id you have specified you need a $("#v65-productdetail-action-wrapper").before($(".PageText_L483n").first());

Comment: Try `$("#v65-productdetail-action-wrapper").prepend($(".PageText_L483n").first(), "<br>");` or `$("#v65-productdetail-action-wrapper").prepend($(".PageText_L483n").first(), "<div style='clear:both;'></div>");`

Comment: either you use <br> as winterblood said or replace your spans with divs .. all work fine, span after a span = one line